# Remove items from 'LeftMenuCollect' collection in Leave Request template?

Tags: powerapps

I'm using the Leave Request template and I'm trying to remove the *'About'* and *'My Leave Balance'* menu items from the left menu, however I'm not too sure how to do it since the items are a part of a collection.

I tried the *Remove ThisItem* option which kind of worked, but when I load the app up again it just seems to populate the menu again with all the original items.

I've also tried setting the following in On start too, but that also didn't work:

```
ClearCollect( LeftMenuCollect, Table( { value:"My Leave Requests", }    , { value:"My Leave Balance", } , { value:"Company Holidays", } ) );
```

What is the proper way to remove items from collections such as this?

My other attempt around this was to create an excel table with my own menu items listed and use that as the datasource for the gallery instead.

This works, and I think I'd actually prefer it this way as it's easier for me to update, however it breaks the styling of the menu. I tried fixing this by modifying the colour code from it's original code:

```
If(LeftMenuSelect = ThisItem.Value, RGBA(47,41,43,1), RGBA(12,132,255,1))
```

To this code, where *'LeftMenuList'* is the name of the excel table:

```
If(LeftMenuList = ThisItem.Title, RGBA(47,41,43,1), RGBA(12,132,255,1))
```

What am I doing wrong in regards to referring to the table/datasource?

Answer (score 0):

In the excel table you made, add a field called "Value" next to the "MenuItem" you already have. Put the same content in both of them. This will take care of the color problem; though you will have to delete all the individual connections for pages that you no longer want to exist after that.

Basically "LeftMenuSelect" is not the right variable to modify. You already changed what table it was pulling from, and then you tried to modify the variable to detect which name should be highlighted based on which page you are on. (Which you actually don't want to do.) "Value" is exactly what you would want to modify though. It is, however, easier to just add a Value column to your data than it is to find all instances of it across all pages to modify it.